# What is the issue with the attribution of sessions traffic data in GA4?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have GA4 data in BigQuery. I then extracted the data to Snowflake due to costs. But the logic is the same.

I am using the following code:

```
with prep as (
select
   user_pseudo_id,
   ga_session_id,
   source,
   count(event_name) as events,
   count (distinct case when session_engaged = 1 then concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) end ) as sessions_eng
   
from
    cdp_ga4_raw.raw_events_pivot
where event_date = '20230308'
group by
    user_pseudo_id,
    ga_session_id, source, medium)
select
    coalesce(source,'(direct)') as source_session,
    count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as total_users,
    count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id)) as sessions,
    sum(sessions_eng) as sessions_engaged,
    sum(events) as events
from
    prep
group by
    source_session
order by
    sessions desc
    limit 10
;
```

I know that values won't match. But I wonder why does the "direct" source is so much more different from what is in GA4 UI.

There are GA4 results

[image]

These are Google Bigquery results

[image]

Huge differences as you can see...

After investigation, I know that there is a misattribution behind this. This is something that I've read:

> One of the most annoying bugs in GA4 (at least for users of the GA4 data export) is the incorrect attribution of event traffic data. The issue occurs when a page view event is generated from a Google search ad and the event includes a gclid parameter in the page url, but the event is still attributed to organic or direct traffic.

> As long as you stick to the default traffic_source fields (first user source, medium and campaign) then the traffic source information is correct. But when you query event or session level traffic acquisition fields, like channel grouping, source, medium and campaign, the misattribution will heavily affect your results.

This is supposedly a known issue for quite a while, but there is no fix...
But I wonder if there's a way to correctly attribute the data to paid search instead of direct.

Can anyone help me with this or give me some directions to whom should I ask these questions?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you are using the `event_params` source or `traffic_source.source`, you will get different values for total distinct users and total distinct sessions for identical time periods.

One source relates to user-level source attribution and the other is event-level attribution [according to Google documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846#zippy=%2Ctraffic-source%2Cevent).  [Confirmed by others](https://zielinsky.alejand.ro/how-to-get-ga4-session-level-traffic-source-attribution-in-bigquery-ef8c8fe994e7), we know that GA4 sessions can have multiple sources.

Given that, the following adjustment should get you a session-level source that is much lower in count due to focusing on one event type and one source per session:

```
    with prep as (
select
   user_pseudo_id,
   (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id') as ga_session_id,
   max((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'source')) as source,
   event_name as events 
from
    your_table
    WHERE event_name = "page_view"
    GROUP BY 1,2,4
),
prep_plus_engagements as (
    SELECT *,
    case when session_engaged = 1 then concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id) end as sessions_eng 
    FROM prep
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT user_pseudo_id,
    (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id') as ga_session_id,
    (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged') as session_engaged from
    `gahitlevelanalytics.analytics_326889090.events_20231018`
    WHERE event_name = "session_start") USING (user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id)
)
select
    coalesce(source,'(direct)') as source_session,
    count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as total_users,
    count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id)) as sessions,
    count(sessions_eng) as sessions_engaged,
    count(events) as events
from
    prep_plus_engagements
group by
    source_session
order by
    sessions desc
    limit 10
;
```